# How to remove duplicates from the output?

Tags: python

```
from math import *

list = []
for i in range(1, 101):
  for e in range(1, 101):
    c = pow(i, 2) + pow(e, 2)
    c = sqrt(c)
    d = c.is_integer()
    if d:
      list.append(i)
      list.append(e)
      list.append(c)
      print(i, e, c)
```

This code looks for [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) which have sides as whole numbers. I get:

```
3 4 5.0
4 3 5.0
5 12 13.0
6 8 10.0
7 24 25.0
8 6 10.0
8 15 17.0
9 12 15.0
9 40 41.0
10 24 26.0
11 60 61.0
12 5 13.0
12 9 15.0
12 16 20.0
12 35 37.0
13 84 85.0
14 48 50.0
15 8 17.0
15 20 25.0
15 36 39.0
16 12 20.0
16 30 34.0
16 63 65.0
18 24 30.0
18 80 82.0
20 15 25.0
20 21 29.0
20 48 52.0
20 99 101.0
21 20 29.0
21 28 35.0
21 72 75.0
24 7 25.0
24 10 26.0
24 18 30.0
24 32 40.0
24 45 51.0
24 70 74.0
25 60 65.0
27 36 45.0
28 21 35.0
28 45 53.0
28 96 100.0
30 16 34.0
30 40 50.0
30 72 78.0
32 24 40.0
32 60 68.0
33 44 55.0
33 56 65.0
35 12 37.0
35 84 91.0
36 15 39.0
36 27 45.0
36 48 60.0
36 77 85.0
39 52 65.0
39 80 89.0
40 9 41.0
40 30 50.0
40 42 58.0
40 75 85.0
40 96 104.0
42 40 58.0
42 56 70.0
44 33 55.0
45 24 51.0
45 28 53.0
45 60 75.0
48 14 50.0
48 20 52.0
48 36 60.0
48 55 73.0
48 64 80.0
48 90 102.0
51 68 85.0
52 39 65.0
54 72 90.0
55 48 73.0
56 33 65.0
56 42 70.0
56 90 106.0
57 76 95.0
60 11 61.0
60 25 65.0
60 32 68.0
60 45 75.0
60 63 87.0
60 80 100.0
60 91 109.0
63 16 65.0
63 60 87.0
63 84 105.0
64 48 80.0
65 72 97.0
66 88 110.0
68 51 85.0
69 92 115.0
70 24 74.0
72 21 75.0
72 30 78.0
72 54 90.0
72 65 97.0
72 96 120.0
75 40 85.0
75 100 125.0
76 57 95.0
77 36 85.0
80 18 82.0
80 39 89.0
80 60 100.0
80 84 116.0
84 13 85.0
84 35 91.0
84 63 105.0
84 80 116.0
88 66 110.0
90 48 102.0
90 56 106.0
91 60 109.0
92 69 115.0
96 28 100.0
96 40 104.0
96 72 120.0
99 20 101.0
100 75 125.0
```

There are duplicates, for example `3 4 5.0` and `4 3 5.0`. How can I get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: Use `for e in range(i+1, 101)` so the second number is always higher than the first.

Comment: Also, don't call your variable `list`. That word already means something in python, and you'll end up shadowing the original meaning by defining a variable with the same name

Comment: Beside the point, but the code style could be better: Reassigning `c` is confusing; you can just `c = sqrt(pow(i, 2) + pow(e, 2))`. `d` is only used once, so might as well just `if c.is_integer():`. `list` is unused, but I think you want `list.append((i, e, c))`. Lastly, `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the builtin `list` type; It'd be better to use a more descriptive name, like say, `triples`, or at least something like `lst`.

Comment: Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. I think you want, "How do I get Pythagorean triples without duplicates?"

Comment: This produces false positives (for example `i=93222358 e=93222358 c=131836323`, `i=131836323 e=131836323 c=186444716`, `i=170450288 e=170450288 c=241053109`).

Answer (score 3):

Barmar has hit upon it in comments, start your `b` range from from `a+1` to ensure that the digits will always be in ascending order. Moreover, this can be done with one generator expression:

```
>>> print(*((a, b, c)
...         for a in range(1, 101)
...         for b in range(a+1, 101)
...         for c in (math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2)),)
...         if c.is_integer()),
...       sep='\n')
(3, 4, 5.0)
(5, 12, 13.0)
(6, 8, 10.0)
(7, 24, 25.0)
(8, 15, 17.0)
(9, 12, 15.0)
(9, 40, 41.0)
(10, 24, 26.0)
(11, 60, 61.0)
(12, 16, 20.0)
(12, 35, 37.0)
(13, 84, 85.0)
(14, 48, 50.0)
(15, 20, 25.0)
(15, 36, 39.0)
(16, 30, 34.0)
(16, 63, 65.0)
(18, 24, 30.0)
(18, 80, 82.0)
(20, 21, 29.0)
(20, 48, 52.0)
(20, 99, 101.0)
(21, 28, 35.0)
(21, 72, 75.0)
(24, 32, 40.0)
(24, 45, 51.0)
(24, 70, 74.0)
(25, 60, 65.0)
(27, 36, 45.0)
(28, 45, 53.0)
(28, 96, 100.0)
(30, 40, 50.0)
(30, 72, 78.0)
(32, 60, 68.0)
(33, 44, 55.0)
(33, 56, 65.0)
(35, 84, 91.0)
(36, 48, 60.0)
(36, 77, 85.0)
(39, 52, 65.0)
(39, 80, 89.0)
(40, 42, 58.0)
(40, 75, 85.0)
(40, 96, 104.0)
(42, 56, 70.0)
(45, 60, 75.0)
(48, 55, 73.0)
(48, 64, 80.0)
(48, 90, 102.0)
(51, 68, 85.0)
(54, 72, 90.0)
(56, 90, 106.0)
(57, 76, 95.0)
(60, 63, 87.0)
(60, 80, 100.0)
(60, 91, 109.0)
(63, 84, 105.0)
(65, 72, 97.0)
(66, 88, 110.0)
(69, 92, 115.0)
(72, 96, 120.0)
(75, 100, 125.0)
(80, 84, 116.0)
```

Alternatively, using for loops to achieve the same:

```
for a in range(1, 101):
  for b in range(a+1, 101):
    c = math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2))
    if c.is_integer():
      print((a, b, c))
```

[image: "for b in range(a+1, ...)" animated]

Creating a *list* of these either means appending to a list in the conditional in the latter version, or converting the generator expression to a list comprehension:

```
triples = [
  (a, b, c)
  for a in range(1, 101)
  for b in range(a+1, 101)
  for c in (math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2)),)
  if c.is_integer()
]
```

Comment: Of course, a follow-up question would be whether `(3, 4, 5)` and `(6, 8, 10)` are really unique triples.